# Jmeter в CLI режиме потребляет больше памяти чем в графическом

Tags: java, память, тестирование, jmeter, нагрузочное-тестирование

Использую JRE 8 версии. Делал много запусков. В один прекрасный момент Jmeter стал использовать JDK и память стала уходить супер быстро. Изменил переменную PATH И JAVA HOME. Теперь в не графическом режиме опять используется JRE. Однако CLI режим по прежнему потребляет в два раза больше памяти чем графический. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Может быть потому что для разных режимов устанавливаются различные значения `Xmx`? Покопайтесь в скриптах, которые запускают эти два режима.

Comment: Как вы определяете, сколько памяти потребляет процес?

Comment: Смотрю через Task manager

Comment: Может быть потому что для разных режимов устанавливаются различные значения Xmx? Покопайтесь в скриптах, которые запускают эти два режима. - Покопался, изменил параметры Xms и Xml. Это избавило от проблемы выдачи сообщения Java heap space